# How do I achieve these tanned skin tones in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, skin-tones

I came across this image and I know this guy just uses Lr. How is he achieving the tanned/golden skin tone? In the first image below, I also noticed the sky is a deep blue so I don't see much split toning.

In the second image, that skin tone is still achieved but it seems more with split toning?

I know the time of day/sunset is important but the first is not really at that time of day. I tried to calibrate to give more of golden colour but it's not really working!

Any ideas? :)

[image: Ref: Image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it was explicitily done in post? Looking at the angles of shadows in the first picture the sun would have produced some fantastic light and could have very well been the subjects natural tones.

Comment: Split toning. You used that term. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: The skin in the first one matches the pottery hanging on the wall, which looks accurate. I'm going for spray on tan in that one. It's getting to be a "thing" with brides in my area. It seems they can't get married without one.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the banding in the shadows of the first image. The green and purple hues of the bands at various luminance levels are indicative of heavy use of the sliders in the HSL module. Considering that the whites are neutral without being blown out the overall white balance seems to be fairly neutral. The pottery on the walls looks about right in terms of hue. That the bride's skin matches the pottery screams "spray-on tan" to me.

The second one just looks like it has an orange filter applied, either a physical filter in front of the lens as shot or applied in post. There are plenty of filter plugins available for Lightroom that will mimic the effect of specific filters that have been around forever: Wratten #9 (Yellow), #15 (Yellow), #16 (Orange), #21 (Orange), etc.